# Syntax error in /etc/sudoers

Tags: raspbian, sudo

For no reason that I can figure, my Raspbian install on my Pi stopped letting me sudo. I've been able to get into a kind of single-user mode using [this page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=109612), but now that I'm there, I can't figure out what the error is. I've compared it to the sudoers file on my Pi 2, and they look nearly identical. It says there's a syntax error near line 27.
Here's what I see in visudo:
[image: Imgur]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the output of ls -la /etc/sudoers.d

Comment: Hmm. Seems pretty empty. And the README seems empty. [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/fvEik0C.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion of Steve Robillard, I checked the contents of /etc/sudoers.d, where I found only a README, which didn't output anything when I cat'd it. Then I took a look on my other Pi, and found it also had the single README file, but the proper one just contained a commented message about itself. Then I went back to the pi with the problem, and overwrote /etc/sudoers.d/README with `# this is a test file`, and now everything is working again.

What I suspect happened is that that README somehow got corrupted and that tripped up the system even though there was no problem with /etc/sudoers itself.